# Mobile application in flash builder with web service

Tags: web-services, flash-builder, mobile-application

I am trying to create an application in flash builder 4.5.1 and try to access web service from it can anyone guide me how to do this ? I have created a simple helloworld webservice in netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody for your time I found the solution how to access web service from flash builder i found the perfect example in the following link

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/complex-web-services-in-flash-builder-4/